# Unit testing angular component which uses input.required

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test, angular-signals

I'm trying to unit test one of my components which has

```
 regexCtrl = input.required<FormControl<string>>({alias: 'regex'});
```

After some Googling, this was, more or less, what I thing should be to correct way

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.componentRef.setInput('regex', new FormControl(''));
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Which gives an error:

```
console.error
    NG0303: Can't set value of the 'regex' input on the 'MyComponent' component. Make sure that the 'regex' property is annotated with @Input() or a mapped @Input('regex') exists.
```

The weird thing is, is that the error suggests that I need to annotate the input with @Input, which is not needed anymore (I'm using angular 17.0.3)

Just in case the `alias` didn't work as expected in my spec file, I also tried to set  `regexCtrl` , which resulted in the same error

Any suggestions how this is done now?

UPDATE: Found a solution which at least works and seems a step into the right direction (only the cast feels off)

```
 component.regexCtrl = computed(() => new FormControl('')) as InputSignal<FormControl<string>>;
```

**UPDATE2**: After updating it works. I think it was related to the `jest` dependencies (I update angular, jest and nx so I'm not really sure which one did the trick). Now I can just do:

```
 fixture.componentRef.setInput('regex', new FormControl());
```

Comment: Age you using Jest?

Comment: Yes, it is jest

Comment: Try to update, it was a [known issue](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/2246) fixed quite recently

Comment: Yep thats it thnx! After I updated it works as expected. I've included it in my question at the end!